# string concatenation and addition

Tags: javascript, addition

When I try to do addition:

```
let x = "5" + 2 + 3;
//output 523

let x = 2 + 3 + "5";
// output 55
```

I know JavaScript concatenates the integers, but I was expecting "55" in both cases.

As 2+3 will be added to 5 and then concatenated to "5". Please can someone explain to me
what is happening under the hood.

I am new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pluses are evaluated from left to right.
So first `"5"+2` is evaluated (result is `"52"`), and then `"52"+3` gives `"523"`.